# java object hierarchy, and passing objects to functions

Tags: java, generics, object

I have created a TreeMap like so:

```
TreeMap<Integer, ArrayList<MyClass>> wrap = new TreeMap<Integer, ArrayList<MyClass>>();
```

I have created a constructor like so:

```
public foo (TreeMap<Integer, Collection<Spot> > objects) {
     this.field = objects;
}
```

However, eclipse gives me a red squigly when I use the constructor, with my `wrap` variable as the single parameter:

```
The constructor foo(TreeMap<Integer,ArrayList<Spot>>) is undefined
```

An ArrayList is a type of Collection...yes? So why is this not working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generics don't work as you think they do in this case.

What you need is something similar to:

```
public foo (TreeMap<Integer, ? extends Collection<Spot> > objects) {
     this.field = objects;
}
```

The `?` is called a wild card.  It will allow you to pass in a `Collection`, or anything that extends/implements `Collection`.

The line `? extends Collection<Spot>` reads like:

> Something that extends a Collection.